# pyodbc - cannot delete from MSSQL tables

Tags: python, pyodbc

Trying to delete some of the table entries by using pyodbc in database results in nothing happening. I know for sure that database connection is working as intended, can select data. Perhaps any suggestions what could be the cause?

```
    get_user_id = conn.cursor()
    get_user_id.execute('''
                            SELECT b.UserId
                            FROM Bindery b
                            INNER JOIN ActiveUser au 
                            ON au.Id = b.UserId
                            WHERE au.UserId = ?
                            ''', user_to_kick)
    id_list = [id[0] for id in get_user_id.fetchall()]
    delete_user = conn.cursor()
    #delete from bindery first
    delete_user.execute('''
                        DELETE FROM Bindery
                        WHERE UserId in (?)
                        ''', id_list)
    conn.commit
    #delete from active user list
    delete_user.execute('''
                        DELETE FROM ActiveUser
                        WHERE UserId = ?
                        ''', user_to_kick)
    conn.commit
    delete_user.close()
    conn.close
```

This is a code block that should imo trigger the delete query, but nothing happens. Select query does indeed get the data.

**UPDATE:**

After some adjustments and passing list as a parameter fixed, the delete query now indeed works as intended.

```
    get_user_id = conn.cursor()
    get_user_id.execute('''
                            SELECT b.UserId
                            FROM Bindery b
                            INNER JOIN ActiveUser au 
                            ON au.Id = b.UserId
                            WHERE au.UserId = ?
                            ''', user_to_kick)
    id_list = [id[0] for id in get_user_id.fetchall()]
    placeholders = ", ".join(["?"] * len(id_list))
    sql = 'DELETE FROM Bindery\
           WHERE UserId in (%s)' % placeholders
    delete_user = conn.cursor()
    #delete from bindery first
    delete_user.execute(sql, id_list)
    conn.commit()
    #delete from active user list
    delete_user.execute('''
                        DELETE FROM ActiveUser
                        WHERE UserId = ?
                        ''', user_to_kick)
    conn.commit()
    get_user_id.close()
    delete_user.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: `conn.commit` is a function, you need to call it with `conn.commit()`

Comment: You are indeed right. I had to fiddle like 10 more minutes and now all works. Code needed to be adjusted as well.